rotation using base snap
I'm trying to use base snapping to rotate my upper cube so the edge will be overlap with the edge of the lower cube. Press R to rotate then press B and select the first edge and then target edge. But it doesn't work :

right now, I have to do quite long process : extract the edge from each of the cubes then 'separate' as new object , then F to create face then create new orientation from this face. Finally use this orientation to rotate.
Any faster method ?

Can you share a bit more about what it is you're actually trying to accomplish? You aren't just rotating cubes together, what is the actual end goal. There are some ways to do this, but most are gonna be a little awkward like this. It's possible that you could go about the entire issue in a way that prevents this problem from ever arising. Sometimes it's better to think about if the method you chose is even good at all, rather than trying to figure out how to make that method work, just cause you already went with it.
